# How do I access information from multiple associated models in the Controller in an effiecient manner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord, controller

First, some background.

My application models are like so:

```
  User has_many :subscriptions; has_many :courses, :through => :subscriptions
Subscription belongs_to :course, :user
  Course has_many :subscriptions; has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions
```

Subscription is a join table used to store information such as state (:active, :inactive, :failed, :passed, :unpaid) as well as serve as a connector to all the information that comes with taking a course (such as the Grade model(not yet added), the Payment model(work in progress), etc).

I want to add the Payment model to store a history of payments on a subscription. Each payment can be for one or more subscriptions. So far, I've tried a `Payment has_many :subscriptions`, but **I'm having trouble with the controller logic** and I'm thinking maybe there's a better way to associate the models for "a Payment from a User on a Subscription to a Course."

Technically speaking, in a payment show action, I would need information from each of these models (course.name, user_id of user who paid, payment.amount, all of which are connected to a Subscription) and in a Payment.create action, I'd need to set the state of the subscription (that I can do).

If this is a logical/efficient way to associate the various models, how do I access the needed information(some information from each model course, user, payment, and subscription) in the Payment show action with minimal database calls? I'm using `Rails 3.2/Ruby 1.9` and would like to stick with ActiveRecord/ARel instead of straight sql statements. I'm open to "you're doing it wrong" answers as well. If changing the associations will make it more efficient to access the tables from the controller, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@D3mon-1stVFW's answer set me on the right track to figure this problem out.

For the Payment show action, the queries would go something like:

```
@payment = Payment.find_by_id(params[:id])
@subscriptions = @payment.subscriptions.includes(:course, :user)
```

This will make it possible to access the course and user data associated with a subscription like so:

```
<% @subscriptions.each do |subscription|%>
  <%= subscription.payment.amount %>
  <%= subscription.user.email %>
  <%= subscription.course.name %>
  <%= subscription.state  %>
<% end%>
```

For a payment new/create action where there is not yet a `payment.id`, the queries are slightly different:

```
@unpaid_subs = Subscription.where(:user_id => current_user.id).unpaid.includes(:course)
@payment = Payment.new
```

Where `current_user` is the user that is going to pay(create a new payment) and `.unpaid` is a scope on the `Subscription` model that looks like this:

```
scope :unpaid, -> { where('subscriptions.payment_id' => nil)}
```

And in the view, you can access the data in the same way as with the show view:

```
<% @unpaid_subs.each do |sub| %>
  <%= sub.course.name %> | <%= sub.course.credits %><br />
<% end %>
```

My main point of confusion had been that I didn't know you could access parent associations from the child. Subscription belongs_to Courses, yet you can still do `subscription.course.something`.

Answer (score 1):

Do (in `config/routes.rb`)

```
resources :users do
  resources :courses do
    resources :subscriptions
  end
end
```

Which will allow you to do `@user.courses.subscriptions`

If you want to go from `courses` back to `users`, for example, you can modify the route to be like

```
resources :users, :shallow => true do
 #...
end
```

**Edit:**

For Payment, I would just do like you said `has_many :subscriptions`

When you show a payment.  You would do something like

```
payment_history = Payment.find(params[:id])
@subscriptions = payment_history.subscriptions
```

Now you have the list of subscriptions for the link to that payment history, for example

You would loop in the view and display each subscription

```
<% @subscriptions.each do |subscription|%>
  <%= subscription.payment.id %>
  <%= subscription.users.size %>
  <%= subscription.courses.size %>
  <%= subscription.paying_user.name  %> <!-- or whereever it exists-->
<% end%>
```

You need to make sure you have a route for that and restart the server after you change the routes

```
resources :payments, :shallow => true do
   resources :subscriptions
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know I'm new to Rails and programming in general, but I'm pretty sure that routes don't generate the methods to access the database. Also, I'm trying to follow the rule-of-thumb that's in the rails guide on routing which says, "Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep." I didn't know about the `:shallow` option and will research that.

Comment: Good to know.  I did not know about the 1 level.  Thanks. Edit:  after reading more I think it is safe to have two levels deep when you need it.  Must have been for Rails 2.  I could be wrong.

Comment: That's true. It is just a guideline, not a rule. However, the routes aren't the problem. They don't have anything to do with the generation of methods like `@model.children_models`. That's defined by the associations between models. I updated the question to make it a bit more clear and fixed an error in my model associations (sorry about that).

Comment: I edited your answer a bit to make it work for my specific case. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: You're edited answer mostly answered my question, but leaves out `includes(:course, :user)`, which is needed to make the view calls below work properly (otherwise, you get a No Method Error for nil::NilClass). I tried editing the answer to included that information, but it wasn't accepted for some reason. If you want the accepted answer, you can add that part. Otherwise, I'll upvote your answer and add one myself explaning the complete solution. Either way, thanks a bunch for helping me with this problem.

Comment: I think it is better to add your detailed fix to help others if they encounter the same issue.  Glad to know you got it sorted.